# Computation of Easter date (UK statutory method)

Tags: math-history, calendar-computations

The statutory method for the computation of Easter in the UK (and presumably also the USA) is contained in the *Calendar (New Style) Act 1750*. This is the same Act which moved the British Empire from the Julian calendar and onto the Gregorian. The Act and the method it specifies remains in legal force in the UK.

This employs a tabular method of calculating Easter which does not explicitly refer to the "epact" (which from what I gather, is the standard way in which the Roman Catholic Church makes the calculation).

The Act as currently in force is reproduced here (the relevant tables are reproduced as images toward the end of the document): https://www.legislation.gov.uk/apgb/Geo2/24/23/section/6

Complicating the matter, some of the tables which were originally enacted, and which gave detailed data for dates before 1900, were repealed by the Statute Law (Repeals) Act 1948, and so they are not reproduced in the current legislation. However, this repeal appears also to have deleted a block of text from the modern reproduction. The original Act, therefore, can be viewed in full here (page 206 onwards): https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=rLsuAAAAIAAJ&lr&pg=PA206

I have also stumbled on a link that apparently reproduces the same content in HTML, and with modern typesetting, but does not attempt to provide any further explanation: [http://www.eskimo.com/~lhowell/bcp1662/info/tables/index.html](http://www.eskimo.com/%7Elhowell/bcp1662/info/tables/index.html)

**Basically I ask, does anyone have a comprehensive mathematical analysis of this specific statutory method? That is, how the typeset tables are produced from first principles, and how the tables are then worked in an explicit, step-by-step fashion?**

I'm broadly familiar with the concepts and terminology involved in the Easter calculation, but in terms of applying this method I find I'm falling down even at the very outset: *"To find the Dominical or Sunday Letter, according to the Calendar, until the Year 1799 inclusive, add to the Year of our Lord its Fourth Part, omitting Fractions;"*.

What does it mean, "add to the Year ... its fourth part"? The obvious modern interpretation of this is to add a quarter again - multiply the year by 1.25 and then floor - but I can't find any basis to be certain of this, or understand why such an apparently arbitrary constant is employed.

Comment: A little detail: I am not a native English speaker, but I would use the term: "computation of Easter $\color{red}{time}$"

Comment: @JeanMarie, I've amended it to "computation of Easter date".

Comment: Not a mathematical analysis, but you can find a clear description of the algorithm in *The Art of Computer Programming, Volume 1: Fundamental Algorithms, Second Edition*  by Donald Knuth.  See Exercise 14, section 1.3.2, "Algorithm E (Date of Easter)".

Comment: @awkward Excellent reference. See as well https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computus.

Comment: @awkward, I've managed to get a copy of TAOCP, and that algorithm at 1.3.2 looks to me like the Gauss algorithm, not the UK statutory method. Please, will you and Jean Marie engage with the substance of the question, which is not about any old method of calculating Easter, but about the *specific legal method*. You will almost certainly have to read the linked legislation as a starting point.

Comment: @JeanMarie, same as above in my comment to Awkward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so I *think* I've sort of got the process (or at least, I'm getting the right answers out). I'll go through it for this year for an example:

1. First we need to find the Sunday Letter for our year from Table I. To do this:

   1. Ignoring the stupid way it's worded, we first look at the table, and find the century that we're in. In our case, that's $2000$. We then go to the very top of that column, and get the magic number: in our case, $6$.
   2. We then multiply the current year by $1.25$ and floor (giving $2525$), and add that to our magic number, giving $2531$. We take the remainder of that when divided by $7$ ($4$ in our case), then look *that* number up in the row that we got our magic number from, giving our Sunday Letter as $D$ (this is promising: easter is after the leap day, at which point we will indeed be in a "$D$" year).
2. Now, we go down to the writing next to Table II:

   1. We first round the year down to the nearest century ($2000$ for our example), and find our "number or cypher" (hereafter "cypher number"). In this case, that cypher number is $2$.
   2. We then find the cypher number in *each column* of Table III (or just find it in the column matching your golden number, if you already know that).
   3. Out of all of those numbers, only one (the one in the column for your golden number, so this tells you that number as well) will match up with your Sunday Letter from the first table.
   4. The date marked on that line gives you the Eclesiastical Paschal Full Moon for your year (in our case, the 5th of April). Easter is the Sunday following that, and since the 5th of April happens to have been a Sunday this year, Easter this year was on the 12th of April.

---

As for why that works, we'll look at each part in turn:

1. The Sunday Letter table seems to be a modified version of [De Morgan's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominical_letter#De_Morgan%27s_rule): using the third equivalent, the $1.25$ comes from the $y + \left\lfloor\frac{y}{4}\right\rfloor$ part, the "magic number" is the $5(c\,\mathrm{mod}\,4) - 1$ part, and everything after that is the same.
2. This is where the epact and golden number are hidden: the column, as mentioned above, where your number appears gives the golden number for the year, and the cypher numbers look to have been computed backwards from the epact ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computus#British_Calendar_Act_and_Book_of_Common_Prayer) claims similarly, though I can't find it in either of the pages that they cite for that claim) then arranged in the tables in such a way as to make everything match up.

---

Incidentally, it does work: [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20150907215917/http://www.merlyn.demon.co.uk/estr-bcp.htm) page has a javascript implementation, which has been verified to match the epact method.

Comment: actually the HTML pages produced by the OP use the golden number: http://www.eskimo.com/%7Elhowell/bcp1662/info/tables/easter.html .

Comment: Thanks for this help which has brought focus. I infer what's going on then with the Sunday letter table, is that the first weekday of the year advances by one per year (i.e. progressing Mon-Sun, then wrapping around, because 364 days make 52 whole weeks, leaving the extra day to make 365, which makes the following year start one weekday later), and an additional advance in a leap year (for a total advance of two in a leap year). So the total number of weekday advances to the current year, is the year count, plus a quarter again. (1/2)

Comment: The non-leap centuries must however be subtracted from that "quarter again" component, and that's what the table does. Does this sound right? (2/2)

Comment: That sounds right to me, yes.

Comment: Excellent. On a further point, do you have any understanding of what causes the discontinuities on April 17/18 in Table 3? I'm aware that some sort of correction exists to prevent Easter falling on April 19 (which was said to be impossible in the previous Julian system), but I can't follow at all how the pattern is derived from first principles.

Comment: Looks like the other way around: the 19th of April is actually the most common date for Easter. I don't have any particular insight on the root causes, but (from reading the wikipedia article), it looks like the council of Nicea required Easter to be no later than the 25th of April (and hence the Paschal full moon to be no later than the 18th), so they bodged it to make it work. It looks like their bodge was essentially to pretend that both the 18th and 19th are a day and a half long. The usual epact methods have a similarly odd bodge at the end.

Comment: @user3482749, what I've read is that under the Julian system, April 18th was the latest possible date as a natural consequence of the 19 possible epacts, so when they adopted the Gregorian reforms, to avoid disrupting that traditional range and potentially celebrating Easter on the hitherto unheard-of 26th April, they insisted the Paschal full moon continue to fall in the same 29 day window (Mr22 to Ap18), even though there are a full 30 different values for the epact. But it's very difficult to understand the correction/bodge clearly, even though its effect can be seen.